# JQuery not keyword

Tags: jquery

```
$("li a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().css({ width: 160 });               
    $("li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    $("#Container").css({ width: 200 }).animate({ width: 700 }, 1000);
});
```

I wanna set width 120 for all li's except current(this).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("li a").click(function() {
      $("li").not($(this).parent()).width(120);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).parent().siblings().css('width',120);
```

Comment: +1. Shame that the first *and* best answer didn't get accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li").not($(this).closest('li')).width(120);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    $(this).parent().siblings().css({ width: 160 })
```

Working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4mXLS/)